# Custom Plugin to Process Form

Tags: module, plugin

I am building a custom plugin to process a form. I am new to custom plugins and after looking at several different tutorials I am stuck on my form action. I would like to access the process form method in the class, is this correct with EE and if so, how do I go about it.

Thanks.

```
class Myform {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->EE =& get_instance();
}

public function form()
{

    $form_data = array(
        "id"    => $this->EE->TMPL->form_id,
        "class" => $this->EE->TMPL->form_class,
        "action" => //process_form()
    );

    $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;

    $form = $this->EE->functions->form_declaration($form_data) . $tagdata . "</form>";

    return $form;
}

public function process_form()
{
    return "testing";
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Usage
 *
 * Plugin Usage
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  string
 */
function usage()
{
    ob_start(); 
    ?>

    Documentation will go here

    <?php
    $buffer = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean(); 

    return $buffer;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

}
// END CLASS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a *plugin* or *module*? Because actions is using in Modules.
You can add new action to the system using next query (usually in function *install*):

```
$sql[] = "INSERT INTO exp_actions (class, method) VALUES ('module_name', 'my_action_procedure')";
```

how to get action id for specific method:

```
 $form_data = array(
        "id"    => $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('form_id',''),
        "class" => $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('form_class',''),
        "action" => ee()->functions->fetch_action_id('module_name', 'process_form');
    );
```

if you don't want to develop module, just give user option to add another template name as base for processing form, like

```
{ext:myform process_uri="home/process" form_id="my-form" form_class="super-form-class"}
```

*home/process*

```
{ext:my_plugin:process_form}
```

Comment: $actionID = ee()->functions->fetch_action_id(__CLASS__, 'process_form'); is better than a custom active record query.

Comment: agree. always forgot about this :)

Comment: rebuilding as module, let me catch up and I'll follow up

Comment: @MaxLazar - thanks for the suggestion on the module. Built successfully! I will accept your answer. One more question or just tell me to ask a new..currently after successful post I am using the default message `$this->EE->output->show_message($data);` Is there a way instead to redirect with the $data to new page or should I set up tags? thanks

Comment: @Bungdaddy - how did you get on with redirecting with the data? I'm also wanting to do that.